# Bottom of vertical scrollbar not visible on a page

Tags: html, css

What is the most common error when I can't see the bottom of the vertical scrollbar on a page and I can't scroll to the bottom of the page and see all the content? I don't know where to start to look really.

an image of that it looks like
http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/2228/croll.png

Comment: Looks like the bottom of your window is being hidden by your taskbar. Maybe you can reduce the size of the window and then drag it to the top. I don't think that is an HTML or CSS issue.

Comment: Another problem might be if the scrollbar is actually on an element *inside* the page, rather than the page itself, and there's an `overflow:hidden` run amok somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Just fixed that issue. Problem was that the scrollbar was generated by a `div` wrapper with `position: fixed;` that had a `scrollbar`, with `body{overflow:hidden;}`.

Thanks to **sdleihssirhc** who put me on the right track.